# check if method exists in subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class (BaseClass) and a subclass (SubClass) that inherits from the BaseClass. One of the operations I want to perform is to send requests from the Base to the Sub but only if there is a method defined for it. Let me demonstrate this with some code:

**BaseClass**:

```
def extract_data extracted_data=Hash.new
  ['attr1','attr2','attr3'].each do |attr|
    extracted_data[attr] = self.send("extract_#{attr}")
  end
  return extracted_data
end
```

**SubClass**:

```
def extract_attr1
  # do something and return a value
end
```

This works prefectly well if there is a method with that name in defined in the Subclass. If its not defined I will get an error. How can I check that a method is defined in a subclass before calling it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just write as below using [`Object#respond_to?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F)

```
extracted_data[attr] = self.send("extract_#{attr}") if self.respond_to?("extract_#{attr}")
```

Comment: Some Ruby programmers do not like `#respond_to?` method, as its certain uses are a sign of *chicken typing*. In this particular case, `#respond_to?` seems ok to me, but some might prefer `NoMethodError` exception handling.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky You means `self.send("extract_#{attr}") rescue NoMethodError`. BTW what is *chicken typing* ?

Comment: In short: `do_something() if self.respond_to('some_possible_function')`

Comment: @Eddie You're missing the question mark in `respond_to?`.